# Make only nested property reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having a data object that consists of properties unrelated to vue/the UI and data that describes the state. Now I only want the `state` to be reactive but I need the entire object initially in the component. I need that vue not modifies the other properties because it messes with another library accessing the other properties. (expects array but gets observer)

Is it possible to only make part of an object reactive?

```
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.untrackedProperty = ...;
        this.state = {
            these: "",
            should: "",
            be: "",
            reactive: ""   
        }
    }
}


// vue component
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            gameState: null
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.game = new Game();
        this.gameState = this.game.state;
    }
}
</script>
```

<strike>Something like that.</strike>
I meant it as "That's how I think it should work - it doesn't, but I think it describes pretty well my intentions"

Comment: Can you give more information what 'exactly' you want ? Not 'something' like ... please provide object and what parts of it you want to be changes and what to not be changed

Comment: Maybe I didn't articulate myself very well, but the data structure is exactly like I described it above. The game object changes, the state changes and the `untrackedProperty` changes, but I don't want Vue to observe the `untrackedProperty` but rather ONLY the `state` property. My understanding is that everything I put in `data` is tracked by Vue, therefore I put only the `state` in data, but this doesn't seem to work because it's not updating properly. If I put the entire `game` object on it, it does update, but it messes with properties I don't want it to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing into your component 2 values:

- *state* this will be tracked
- *untrackedProperty* this will not be tracked

Instead of passing *Game* as a whole object, separate those 2 values

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it. The game object is created inside a Vue component and then passed down. Therefore the question is how to set up the object in the parent component. I thought the question was basic enough, but I will create a sandbox to illustrate the problem/what I need.